# Android setup wizard

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I downloaded the android studio in my, but I run into an issue where it seems that the android studio setup is stuck on starting download too long.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/li42k.png)

I tried reinstalling and try alternatives but it is not working...

Answer (score 0):

That will take time, let it run and it will complete the download and proceed in the installation process